# Is space itself expanding or is it just momentum from the Big Bang carrying things apart?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, big-bang

So, we observe that galaxies are moving apart (on average) and the further away from us they are the faster they are moving away from us.  If space was expanding that would explain this.

However, I imagine that if a primordial explosion happened then at some point close to where the explosion happened things would not move much, and they would be moving faster the further away you were from "ground zero".

But if we were not near ground zero there should be some anisotropy in the speeds we observe, is that correct?  There should be a "ground zero" in the "explosion model", right??

However, regardless of the "ground zero" issue, do we (or could we) distinguish between a uniform "explosion" model and the idea that space is expanding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: "*There should be a 'ground zero' in the "explosion model", right??*" - Correct, but it does not mean that this point can be easily identified. "*But if we were not near ground zero there should be some anisotropy in the speeds we observe, is that correct?*" - No, this is incorrect. The most popular "explosion model" is by Milne, whose student was Walker (the W in FLRW): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne_model - This Wiki article does not do justice to his fascinating model, in which the universe expands *inside* the Big Bang singularity. There is no speed anizotropy in this model.

Comment: Here is essentially the same question answered: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423536/experimental-proof-of-space-expansion

Comment: @pela The question you've linked is NOT a duplicate. There the discussion is about the unproven theoretical speculations of the FLRW model. In contrast, here the OP is asking about a direct experimental evidence, of which none exists, to distinguish between the space expansion and galaxies just flying apart on inertia.

Answer (score 5):

It is a misconception that the big bang happened at a point. It did not. There is no ground zero point (in space) where you could point and say, this is where the explosion happened. Space is expanding everywhere at the same rate, and everything is getting farther away from everything.

Now this is not completely true, because galaxies are getting usually farther away from each other, because in the intergalactic space, expansion is dominant.

But inside galaxies, gravity dominates, so space does not expand inside galaxies.

So on the bigger scale, between the intergalactic voids of space, where expansion dominates space itself is expanding, and this expansion seems to be accelerating. Now an explosion as you say could not do this, because to have an ever accelerating expansion you need more and more energy (whatever is causing expansion, like dark energy or negative density). An explosion cannot do that.

So the big bang did not happen at a point in space, but it happened everywhere at the same time.

There is no center of the universe or as you say a ground zero point.

The universe is not like a ball expanding, there is nothing outside the universe that it is expanding into.

Please see here:

[Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point)

Comment: Got it - that the expansion seems to be accelerating seems very key to me

Comment: Statements in your answer are not based on a direct experimental evidence, but on conclusions of one particular cosmological model developed first by Alexander Friedman of Russia and known as FLRW or, with additional details, as Lambda-CDM. There is no experimental evidence that space expands or that "the Big Bang did not happen at a point" or of the existence of "dark energy". All these are popular, but unproven theoretical speculations based on a very problematic Friedman model. The evidence is that space is flat, for which this model gives non-physical results at time zero (infinite mass).

Comment: @safesphere There is a huge body of evidence showing that space is expanding and all existing evidence points to that. Exactly how fast it is happening, and whether or not the rate of expansion will accelerate (or decelerate) is not something we know.

Comment: @forest Welcome to physics Mr. Security :) Unfortunately your comment is incorrect on both points. It looks like you are confusing the expansion of the universe, for which there indeed is a plenty of evidence, with the expansion of space, for which no direct evidence currently exists. These two concepts are related, but different, because the universe can conceptually expand without the expansion of space, e.g. search for the Milne model. Such evidence is possible, we just don't have it yet. if you believe we do, then perhaps you could clarify what it is.

Comment: @forest You second point is also incorrect. The space expansion is a conclusion of the currrent model of cosmology first developed by Friedman. This model clearly states exactly how the universe expands, with what acceleration or deceleration (except for a brief initial inflation). So, if you believe the official cosmological model known as Lambda-CDM (or FLRW), then we indeed know exactly how space expands, although only theoretically, without a direct experimental evidence. We also have experimental data measuring the acceleration of the expansion of the universe, but not necessarily space.

Comment: @forest Details on acceleration (red line on the plot): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428231/what-happens-if-you-travel-through-space-at-the-same-rate-that-space-expands/428253#428253 - Also details on the evidence for space expansion: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423536/experimental-proof-of-space-expansion

Comment: @safesphere You certainly know more than me on this subject so I don't have a rebuttal. I was under the impression that the general consensus going by this site and similar sites is that the expansion of space was regarded as an established phenomenon.

Comment: @forest You're correct, but with a caveat :)  Space expansion is a result of the Friedman solution that matches observations in other areas. So, if you believe the Friedman solution is correct, then space expands, but with no direct experimental evidence yet. In other solutions, space may or may not expand. FWIW, personally I believe that the Friedman solution is not the correct one, but in the correct solution, space still expands.