# Contractions between big bang and gravitational law

Tags: cosmology, newtonian-gravity, big-bang

If big bang happened then the centre of the universe must be place of big bang.

Let the mass of whole universe be $M$ and mass of small planet or any Astro object be $m$.
Then the Gravitational force between $M$ and $m$ be given by:-
$$lim_{M\to\infty \, m\to0\, r\to\infty} \frac{G_\infty M m}{r^2}\left(1+\left(1+\frac{r}{\delta}\right)\alpha e^\frac{-r}{\delta}\right)$$

Where $\alpha$ and $\delta$ are constant.

Then according to the gravitational law ,,
attraction force on $M$ and $m$ must be equal. Then the acceleration of $m$ will be infinitely high towards $M$ as compare to acceleration of $M$.

Then by this theory universe instead of expanding must be compressing and the shape of the universe must be sphere "if big bang theory is correct."

I want to know whether I'm Right or not.

Comment: The big bang was an expansion of space itself.

Comment: Please read the answers to [Did the Big Bang happen at a point ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point).  The key point (and not one easily understood) is that the universe has no center.

Comment: Every point is a viable center.

Comment: "I want to know whether I'm Right or not."  Your very first sentence is wrong, and therefore the rest is as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a misconception that the big bang happened at a point. It did not. In reality, the big bang happened everywhere in the universe at the same time. There is no center of the universe.

Please see my answer here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/477952/132371