# Does spacetime move? With respect to what?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, spacetime, dark-energy

Can spacetime itself rotate along a body, like a black hole? Would it move like a wave?

Comment: Check [Kerr Metric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric), [FLRW metric](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) and [Gravitational Waves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362097/can-empty-space-rotate-without-frame-dragging

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/423536/experimental-proof-of-space-expansion

Comment: Movement is a change in position with respect to time. Spacetime includes time. What other time parameter could spacetime move with respect to? (Do you mean, can *space* move?)